# How to handle a click on the clock in the settings pane in Oreo+?

Tags: android

I'm trying to handle a click event on the clock on the Settings Pane.  I'm sort of confused on the terminology which isn't helping, but here's a screenshot:

[image: Clock in Settings Pane]

I've got an app that I'm developing (If you're curious it's here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fric.beethovenalarmclock&hl=en)

Anyhow, I'm really not sure what the button does.  The default behavior seems to create a new alarm using the stock Google alarm clock.  When I set an alarm on my app, though, it launches the intent for the wake screen.  I'd like to be able to choose which activity in my app to launch, depending on whether sound is playing, or an alarm is set.

I couldn't find any documentation anywhere on what this button is or how to handle a click on it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you need to perform an action on status bar Clock click. You can create your own Alarms by programmatically and can show lists of those Alarms in your app.

Comment: I'd like my users to be able to modify the next upcoming alarm, instead of just showing the alarm wake screen.  As far as I can tell, clicking on the clock just fires a copy of the next alarm's Pending Intent.